How to Efficiently Combine Date Range Filtering and Vector Similarity Search in Astra DB Using _id Field's Time Dimension?
I want to limit vector similarity searches to a specific day or date range. Can I use the time dimension in Astra DB's _id field (document model) for this? Would Astra DB automatically route the query to the correct partition(s) based on the date range, then perform the similarity search within those partitions?
I know Astra DB indexes all fields, but I want to leverage the primary key's inherent time dimension to optimize the search for better efficiency. Would this approach simulate the default efficiency of vector similarity searches?
Here's my sample code:
const startDate = '2024-10-10T00:00:00Z';
const endDate = '2024-10-12T23:59:59Z';

const cursor = await collection_posts.find(
  {
    _id: { $gte: startDate, $lte: endDate }
  },
  {
    sort: { "$vectorize": stringSearch },
    limit: 3,
    projection: { _id: 1, user_id: 1 } // Specify fields to include
  }
).toArray();

My above question is more design related, i.e astra db best practice for combining time with similarity searches.

Is there a reason you don't want to just use a date field that you can filter using $gte and $lte? You can provide your own _id` rather than have the database generate it, so I don't think there is anything in the filtering that will benefit this search.

I ended up just just using the created_at attribute on the document for date range filtering.  It seems $gte and $lte can only work on dates not on a portion of the ID (which is prefixed by a hex timesstamp).  I tried all sorts of combinations, but the above operations only work on an actual date or number.   Given the ID is neither a date or a number, it simply doesn't work.  It's a shame, but at least I know the limitations now.


My above question is more design related, i.e astra db best practice for combining time with similarity searches.

In theory, what you're trying to do is fine. I've built apps before that have combined an index-based search and a vector search. I would, however, caution you against using the _id in a range-based query.
The reason goes back to Astra's roots in Cassandra. Under the hood, _id is used to compose the primary key, and Cassandra uses that to determine which node the data is on. The database nodes (of course) are completely abstracted away in Astra, but they very much do exist (just run a SELECT * FROM system.peers and you'll see them).
Anyway, once the coordinator sees that it cannot determine an exact node to pull the data from, it will resort to systematically checking each of them. Unfortunately, it will do that without the assistance of an index. Of course, Astra DB will still allow it. But it might not run very performantly.
